# Get Chrome to translate web pages

Tags: chrome-for-android, languages, translate

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy 10 tablet. How can I get Chrome to automatically translate a web page? My laptop will do so, either on its own or by right clicking. I have turned on Google translate, but it never offers to translate anything.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Chrome offers to translate pages written in a language you
>   don't understand.

If this functionality seems to be broken, then you can try some workarounds:

1. **Reset translation preferences**

   - In Chrome settings, go to  Site settings > Google Translate >
     tap **Reset translate settings.**

In most cases you should be now getting the popup that asks if you would like to translate the page.

2. **Using alternative browser with  Language translate add on**

   - Browsers for example [Dolphin browser](http://dolphin.com/download/) have [Dolphin translate add-on](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.DolphinTranslate) which support translation of other languages.

[image]

How to use this add-on:

1. Translate a word or sentence

   - Select a desired sentence on your current page and choose “More”
2. Translate the whole page

   - Select “Dolphin Translate” and choose your target language

Hope this helps